# Is it possible to overwrite a directory with a file in linux

Tags: linux, directory, cp

Can someone please help me with a possible case of accidental deletion on a linux box?

I ran the following command:

```
cp file1 /newdir1/folder1
```

What I intended to do was to copy `file1` to the pre-existing `/newdir1/folder1/` directory. Now when I try to go to `/newdir1` and run `ls` command i see `folder1` which as a file with contents from `file1`, instead of finding the original `folder1`. `Folder1` had some files within as well. I didn't get a warning when i ran the copy command. Is it possible that `folder1` is now deleted? Is there any way to check for it or Is there any way to recover it if it is deleted?

This is what I have checked so far: 
When i type `alias cp` i get `alias cp='cp -i'` 
To check linux version, I browsed to the `/etc/` directory and checked `redhat-release` file and it says "CentOS release 6.4 (Final)"

Thanks

Comment: Was the directory called `folder1` or `Folder1`? Is it possible that that's the source of the confusion?

Comment: @KeithThompson I just found out that the folder was moved without notifying us. A big thank you!

Comment: It helps to always use trailing slashes, so you are explicitly aware you are transferring a file to a directory. In this case, you would have saved yourself a lot of time because you would get an error that says "not a directory"

Comment: @ekaj lesson learnt!

Comment: I have a similar situation. I took the output of an HG command and used the ">" symbol to direct it's output to a file but accidentally targeted directory name instead. There is now a file with the directory's name there containing the output of the HG command.  Odd thing though, it was the root directory of a website and Apache is still serving up the site normally. I'm afraid if I restart Apache or the system I'll loose the link to the site directory.  Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `folder1` item is actually the `file1` file, then there was no preexisting `folder1` directory. The default behavior of `cp` is that if the destination is a directory, the item(s) to be copied will be copied into the destination directory. Note that in Linux, `folder1` and `Folder1` are different, as it is case-sensitive.

Comment: The folder1 item now shows contents from file1. And folder1 directory has disappeared. This folder was present before since i have accessed it. Unfortunately i believe that it was deleted and replaced. It doesnt look like i have a way to find out using history or logs.

Comment: If it was present previously, it was removed prior to the `cp` command you listed being issued.

Comment: That may be a possibility but seems unlikely for someone to go in and delete it. is there any way to check logs or history?

Comment: You would need to look through the `~/.bash_history` files for each user. And it's not a possibility, it is a definite. `cp` does not replace directories when they already exist - it never has and likely never will.

Comment: Thank You. It is a relief to know that, even as i still look for the missing directory. Appreciate your help!

Comment: I just found out that the folder was moved by someone. A BIG Thank You!

Comment: @PC2015: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: @PC2015: favour returned!  **;-)**